# Storing and retrieving $_SESSION variables

Tags: php

I've got a problem. I'm sure I'm being really stupid but I can't seem to be able to rertive a $_SESSION variable. I run throught the code with a variable called $setup which I post each time as reset. Each time I run through the code I increment $setup so it starts off with no value then has the value 1 and then then value 2. When it's one, I set a SESSION to a posted value. The next time when it's two, the SESSION doesn't seem to have a value.

This is the code when the page is loaded:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $setup=$_POST['reset'];
    if ($setup==NULL)
    {
        $setup=0;
    }
    elseif ($setup==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['value1']=$_POST['value1'];
        $value1=$_SESSION['value1'];
    }
    elseif ($setup==2)
    {
        $value1=$_SESSION['value1'];
        $_SESSION['value2']=$_POST['value2'];
        $value2=$_SESSION['value2'];
    }
?>
```

When setup is one I can print out value1 however when setup is two is use this code

```
echo $value2 . " " . $value1 . ".";
```

All I get is value2 followed by a dot. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You should actually get a syntax error. By the way, indent your code, please, it'll help reading it.

Comment: When $setup = 2, the session for value1 is not defined because it is defined only if setup = 1

Comment: Sorry about the indenting. It was indented by I sent it using my iPhone so getting it in as code changed the indenting. If I'd been on a computer there wouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: If value is not defined where setup=2 becuase it will have been defined when setup=1 the first time round. It will always equal one before two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. I has a reset button at the bottom to destroy the session and it had PHP in it. Maybe this question will help anyone else who make this mistake. I can happen.

Answer (score 1):

In this part of your code :

```
elseif ($setup==2)
{
    $value1=$_SESSION['value1'];//HERE
    $_SESSION['value2']=$_POST['value2'];
    $value2=$_SESSION['value2'];
}
```

`$_SESSION['value1']` is **empty** so `$value1` will be empty too , instead of this i suggest this code:

```
elseif ($setup==2)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['value1'])   $value1=$_SESSION['value1'];
    else $value1='Some value for test';

    $value2=$_SESSION['value2'];
}
```

ALSO:

```
 echo $value2 . " " . $value1 ".";
```

Should be :

```
 echo $value2 . " " . $value1 . ".";//if you want dot in the end
```

or :

```
echo $value2 . " " . $value1 ;//without dot int end of line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_POST['reset'])) {
    // do nothing or something more useful
  }
  else {
    if ($_POST['reset'] == 1) {
      $value1 = $_SESSION['value1'] = $_POST['value1'];
    }
    elseif ($_POST['reset'] == 2) {
      $value1 = $_POST['value1']; // $_POST !!! Not $_SESSION['value1'], which is not set here!
      $value2 = $_SESSION['value2'] = $_POST['value2'];
    }
  }
?>


 $value1=$_SESSION['value1']; // you can't do this here ( == 2), because you did not set $_SESSION['value1'] to anything before
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't make my self clear before. I go through the program and each time I increment reset. That means the first time it's zero. We do nothing there and value1 get posted in the form. The second time reset is one so I set the SESSION to the value of the POST and then have another form with value2. The third time reset is two so I set the other SESSION to value two and thought that the first SESSION still had the value from the previous time round.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to echo.

Example:

```
$value1 = "hello";
$value2 = "Richard";

echo $value1." ".$value2;
// will output "hello Richard" (Without the quotes)

//using your code (and syntax corrected)
echo $value1." ".$value2.".";
// will output "hello Richard." (Without the quotes)
```

If you want the dot to be echoed, you need to surround it with quotes "", and to break in and out of PHP vars/text etc in an echo as above.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a concatenating dot before "." string

Should be:

```
echo $value2 . " " . $value1 . ".";
```

Comment: I think all he needs is `echo $value2 . " " . $value1;`

Comment: Is anyone able to help me? I've updated the question to explain better what I was trying to do.